# button text to be changed each time it's clicked/tapped

Tags: java, android

I want my Button text to switch between "Stop" and "Start" every time it's tapped/clicked. how would I do that?

```java
    private Button stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        stop.setText("Stop");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Boolean isStart = true; initialize a global variable


  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.start){ 
            if(isStart){
                stop.setText("Stop")
            }else{
                stop.setText("Start");  
            }
            isStart = !isStart;
        }
    }
```

`v.getId()==R.id.start` - In this code I am checking if you have clicked that button or not. If you have only 1 view which uses `this` as `onClickListener`, then there is no need for that check. If you have multiple items, you should check for which one is clicked (preferably with `switch-case`).

Answer (score -1):

make a boolean for example
Boolean start = false;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (start) {
     stop.setText("Stop");
     start = false;
    } else {
     stop.setText("Start");
     start = true;
}`
```